# Configure Stateless EJB Pool size in Websphere

Tags: websphere, websphere-7, websphere-6.1

I'm looking for a way to configure the **SLSB Pool size in Websphere**. Is it possible to configure it from the Admin Console ? 
Looking at the IBM Red Books it's mentioned how to configure the ORB Pool which is however used by remote EJB clients. My Requests are arriving from the same JVM by servlets 
Thanks
Max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a system property called `com.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer.poolSize` that can be used to tune bean pool sizes.

Comment: See the "EJB container system properties" topic in the InfoCenter: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/rejb_ecnt.html